# Why is there no dedicated MATLAB community?

Tags: discussion

Why is there no dedicated MATLAB community?

Comment: I am not the downvoter, but a question starting with "why" doesn't work well on Stack Exchange unless you show some research efforts and make it more useful to current and future users. A question such as *Where can I ask MATLAB-related questions on SE? with explanation that I tried this and that site and I failed* would not have attracted 5 downvotes.

Comment: @Rathony: I respectfully disagree. I also disagree with the decision to mark this as a duplicate. This question isn't asking where to post a MATLAB question. That question does have an answer, though as pointed out by Glorfindel, it is not the only answer. The META SX site is perfect for discussions about opening a new community. The OP's question is relevant and is not a duplicate: why hasn't anyone made a dedicated MATLAB SX site? A good answer would give reasons.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because not enough people have committed to the [proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/94189/matlab) on Area 51.

Note that Stack Overflow already has a lot of questions about [MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matlab).

Comment: Is using stackoverflow for matlab acceptable ? If so, there is no problem :)

Comment: That depends. If you have a question about programming in MATLAB, it could be on-topic as MATLAB is some kind of programming language. It should meet the standards of Stack Overflow, though, so be sure to check the help center before asking.